# How do i access client webcam using my webpage for realtime ML predictions?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

I am trying to create a website where i could access the webcam of people visiting my website and send the frames to my server to process it in realtime and send it back to the client for streaming my predicted images as video. I am using flask to host my server.

```
#server api
@app.route('/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        img_requested = request.get_json(force=True)
        img=img_requested['files']
        #My prediction ML model over here
        
        mean=int(np.mean(img)) #for example
        #end
        
        return jsonify(result=mean)
#end
```

Comment: What specifically is the issue? How exactly is that code related to your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***MediaDevices.getUserMedia()*** to access the media inputs.
The MediaDevices.getUserMedia() method prompts the user for permission to use a media input which produces a MediaStream with tracks containing the requested types of media. That stream can include, for example, a video track (produced by either a hardware or virtual video source such as a camera, video recording device, screen sharing service, and so forth), an audio track (similarly, produced by a physical or virtual audio source like a microphone, A/D converter, or the like), and possibly other track types.

**Reference:**

[MDN Webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

Comment: If this helped you can you please accept it as answer?